# SSIS File locked

Tags: ssis

I am using a package which zips a large file (12 gb). 
However, when it zips the file it locks it and the file is inaccessible, which causes the package to fail.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to zip the file?

Comment: Using Winzip in Execute process task executer